# how to get oracle array of object and use them in my code?

Tags: java

I am trying to get array of objects from oracle procedure that I want to use in my code.
I am getting the below error

```
java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to oracle.sql.STRUCT
```

on this line `java.sql.Struct myStruct = java.sql.Struct)resultSet.getObject(1);`

this is my code

```
    CustResponse resp = new CustResponse();

    sqlString = "begin " + procName + "(?,?,?,?,?);end;";
    callstmt = conn.prepareCall(sqlString);
    callstmt.setString(1, Request.getBANK_CLINT());
    callstmt.setString(2, Request.getCLIENT_NBR());
    callstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ARRAY,"BANK_RECORD_OBJ_ARRAY");
    callstmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
    callstmt.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);

    callstmt.execute();

    resp.setCode(callstmt.getString(4));
    resp.setDescription(callstmt.getString(5));
    ARRAY objArray = (ARRAY) ((weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Array) (callstmt).getObject(3)).unwrap(ARRAY.class);
    resultSet = objArray.getResultSet();
    ResponseCustBodyType[] responseCustBodyType = new ResponseCustBodyType[resultSet.getFetchSize()];
    while (resultSet.next())
    {
        i = i+1;
        java.sql.Struct myStruct = (java.sql.Struct)resultSet.getObject(1);
        Object[] bankInfoStruct = myStruct.getAttributes();
        responseCustBodyType[i].setLOAN_REF(bankInfoStruct[1].toString());
        responseCustBodyType[i].setLOAN_TYPE(bankInfoStruct[2].toString());
        responseCustBodyType[i].setLOAN_AMOUNT(new BigDecimal(bankInfoStruct[3].toString()));
        responseCustBodyType[i].setLAON_CY(bankInfoStruct[4].toString());
        try {
            responseCustBodyType[i].setAPP_DATE(formatter1.parse(bankInfoStruct[5].toString()));
            } 
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
          text = e.toString();
        }
        responseCustBodyType[i].setSTATUS(bankInfoStruct[6].toString());
        responseCustBodyType[i].setREJ_REASON(bankInfoStruct[7].toString());

    }
    resp.setResponseCustBodyType(responseCustBodyType);
    conn.close();
    return resp;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error you posted it looks like resultSet.getObject(1) returns a java.math.BigDecimal object, not a java.sql.Struct.